# Are there quarantine themed beers?

Tags: recommendations, craft-beers

Are there any craft beers themed for quarantine or confinement? Are any beers specifically marketed for this type of occasion?

Comment: Not quite what you're asking for but Untapped have an "Untapped at home" option to check in beers. As well as that - a lot of beer subscription companies are doing tasting nights etc. The idea is you order the crate and log on once a week to virtually "share" it with others online.

Answer (score 3):

**Are there quarantine themed beers?**

What about the obvious: [Corona beer](https://www.the-postillon.com/2020/01/Corona-Ebola.html)!

> The novel coronavirus pandemic has temporarily killed all production of Corona beer — but not because of the fake rumours or jokes linking it to the disease.
>
> Grupo Modelo, the company that brews Corona beer in Mexico, has been forced to temporarily suspend production under the country’s lockdown measures to slow the spread of COVID-19, the disease caused by the virus. - [Corona beer production halts due to coronavirus pandemic](https://globalnews.ca/news/6772814/coronavirus-corona-beer/)

It looks officially quarantined to me!

As a [joke](https://www.the-postillon.com/2020/01/Corona-Ebola.html) they should perhaps rename it Ebola in lieu of Corona!

[image]

I will say this at least: Doing external maintenance in town I find empty Corona beer cans or bottles every day!

[image: Black Plague Beer]

[Black Plague craft beer](https://blackplaguebrewing.com/) might fit the bill also.

[image: Baphomet - Graphic Stein]

[Baphomet - Graphic Stein](https://www.munkstein.com/shop/baphomet-graphic-stein)

If you can not find a ***”quarantine beer”*** in your neighbourhood or home, perhaps to can just go ahead and drink your favourite beer in a **beer stein**. After all they came out with lids during the bubonic plague as a means to reduce infections from insects.

> Some 500 years ago Europe was inundated with swarms of flies during the summer months. This combined with memories of the plague called for some sort of action by citizens.
>
> By the 1500s folks in Germany had figured out that the plague had taken fewer victims in areas that adhered to certain hygienic standards. Cleanliness made a difference in who lived and who died so laws were passed to encourage citizens to leave their filthy ways to the past. One of those laws was that all food and beverage containers had to have lids to protect people from dirty insects.
>
> Covered containers were just a small part of the movement to clean up the community. Another law required that beer could only be made from hops, cereals, yeast and water. This allowed for a better quality beer and did away with the recipes that made beer from rotten bread and such.
>
> Long story short is that the beer industry took off in Germany and has never looked back. The covered beer stein was one innovation that took the fancy of the population long after the threat of disease had passed. The upper class would have had their beer steins made from pewter but the commoner would have embraced those made of pottery. Other mediums used would have included ivory, porcelain, wood, silver and more. Everyone would have had their own individual stein and some of them could be right fancy. All sorts of designs from coats of arms to biblical scenes have turned up on the outside of these steins.
>
> When the industrial age hit beer steins became less expensive to make. Instead of individually molding pottery into a mug they could now be mass produced with each design having a sharpness once associated with the hand made. Strong pottery seemed to be the chosen medium for most steins however glass and pewter did enter the market in a big way.
>
> Finding one of these beauties would be a treat for the collector. Over a 500 year period there would have been lots of steins made in Germany for the discerning collector to find. For the collector of the original steins they can expect to pay hundreds of dollars. Those who collect steins issued by American breweries will pay considerably less. - [Beer stein an invention caused by the bubonic plague](http://houblon.net/spip.php?article4226)

Answer (score 2):

I just made one. I called it "Lockdown Pride", inspired heavily by Dave Line's recipe for London Pride.

- 3.5kg Maris Otter
- 250g Belgian Amber Malt
- 20l water
- Irish moss
- 250g Palm Sugar
- 30g Fuggles
- 75g (+ 10g dry hop) East Kent Goldings
- Lallemand Nottingham yeast

The hops were made into a tea in a pressure cooker for 15mins and then lautered in the post boil cool down. The beer was only boiled for 10 mins. OG 1049, FG 1010, that makes 5.2% abv.

Of course, it's not for sale ... not that the pubs are open anyway.

Comment: In much of the US, stores that sell primarily wine, beer and spirits are are considered essential and are open for business. I think the question is looking for beers available for purchase.

Comment: In the UK the pubs are closed. This is a draft beer but it cannot currently be sold ...

Comment: Pubs and bars are closed in most of the US. Stores that sell alcohol aren’t.

Comment: In Canada  likewise, they are closed.